# how to use reference in between two different MongoDB databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I have two MongoDB Databases DB1 and DB2 (Databases not collections)

Db1 has a collection named User which contains all the data of the users.

DB2 has a collection named blogs which contains blog data

for some reason User and Blog collection are in two different databases DB1 and DB2 respectively

now Blog schema has a userId property which tells which user posted it

Now My question is i want to use mongoose reference in place of userId so i can get user data when i populate it...but because User collection is in DB1 i am not able to do it

blog schema{

title:string,

content: string,

userId: {
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "User"
},

}

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to populate across databases as it states in the mongoose docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#cross-db-populate

You would need to have access to the model instance either when referencing it in the parent schema (example 1) or when performing the actual populate (example 2).

**Example 1 from the docs** - Using the model instance when defining the event schema:

```
const db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27000/db1');
const db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27001/db2');

const conversationSchema = new Schema({ numMessages: Number });
const Conversation = db2.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);

const eventSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  conversation: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: Conversation // `ref` is a **Model class**, not a string
  }
});
const Event = db1.model('Event', eventSchema);

//You can then perform a regular population as if they are on the same DB
const events = await Event.find().populate('conversation');
```

**Example 2 from the docs** - Using the model instance when performing the population:

```
const db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27001/db2');

const conversationSchema = new Schema({ numMessages: Number });
const Conversation = db2.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);

//Then pass the model instance as an option to populate() 
const events = await Event.find().populate({ path: 'conversation', model: Conversation });
```